# The string.prefix() operator, does it exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 'string0'.Prefix('string1') === 'string2'
```

I have come across a prefix operator but i cant find any documentation on how to use it **anywhere** on the web - it all gets covered by prefix and suffix operators

Does someone know about it?

Does it even exist?

Comment: No. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype

Comment: As with all objects in JavaScript the string object can be enhanced with custom functions. Your `Prefix` function was probably such an extension somewhere. But what would be the use case for such function, especially if one could simply write `'string1' + 'string0'`.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, that makes more sense now

Comment: @Jonasw thank you for the info too Jonas

Comment: I am new to this and I cant find the close question button, can some admin please close the question? Thank you :)

Comment: @VarmaRamgoolam To remove your question just delete it

Comment: @KScandrett thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone probably create something like the following in the code you're checking out.

```js
String.prototype.Prefix = function(anotherStr) {
  return anotherStr + this;
}

var name = "Jean";
var sentence = "Hi there, ";

alert(name.Prefix(sentence));
```

Checkout this link for more information on `prototypes` in javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype

Note: Keep in mind, extending native types is not considered best practice

Comment: @VarmaRamgoolam did this help you?

Comment: Thank you jean, this indeed helped as I was trying to rebuild the code so I can test it. I came up with this:

<script>

var string0 = "x";
var string1 = "z";
var string2 = "zx";

string0.prototype.Prefix = function(anotherString) {
    return string0 + this;
};


</script>

I am new to the language and still learning it. I am researching for ways to construct the code on my end too.

Comment: @VarmaRamgoolam then mark this answer as "answered" please :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to format my code in the comments so it comes out clean like yours? :)

Comment: @VarmaRamgoolam you have a few issues in your snippet. I updated the answer to include an example. Check it out.

Comment: wonderful, that will help me rebuild it! Thanks a lot Jean! :)

Comment: No worries @VarmaRamgoolam . Just a reminder to mark this question as closed. You'll need to click the following http://imgur.com/oe7mO3R